# RESTful Web Application URLs/URIs

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jaxb

I have the following resource (only relevant methods are shown):

```
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

GroupContainer groups= new GroupContainer(); //holds groups in an arrayList

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String start() {


    StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    htmlBuilder.append("<html>");
    htmlBuilder.append("<body>");
    htmlBuilder.append("<h1>Hello</h1>");


    htmlBuilder.append("<p>Following: groups</p> <br>");
    for(Group g: groups.getGroups()){
        htmlBuilder.append("<p>" + (g.getID() + " | " + g.getName()) + "</p>");

        htmlBuilder.append("<form method='GET' action='myresource/" + g.getID() +"'>"); 
        htmlBuilder.append("<input type='submit' value='view this group'/>");
        htmlBuilder.append("</form>");

        htmlBuilder.append("<form method='DELETE' action='group'>");
        htmlBuilder.append("<input type='submit' value='delete this group'/>");
        htmlBuilder.append("</form>");
    }

    htmlBuilder.append("<a href='http://localhost:8080/myapp/myresource/asXML'>show overwiev as XML</a>");


    htmlBuilder.append("</body>");

    return htmlBuilder.toString();

}


@Path("/{groupid}") 
public GroupResource getGroupByID(@PathParam("groupid") long groupid){

    Group g=null;
    for(int i=0;i!=groups.getGroups().size();++i){
        if(groups.getGroups().get(i).getID()==groupid){
            g= groups.getGroups().get(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    GroupResource grRes= null;
    if(g!=null){
        grRes= new GroupResource(g);
    }

    System.out.println(g.getID());

    return grRes;
}

}
```

and a groupResource looking like this:

```
@Path("group")
public class GroupResource {


public Group group; 

public GroupResource(Group group){
    this.group= group;
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String listGroups(){


    StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    htmlBuilder.append("<html>");
    htmlBuilder.append("<body>");
    htmlBuilder.append("<h1>Displaying Group</h1>");

    for(Person g: group.getMembers()){
        htmlBuilder.append("<p>" + (g.getID() + " | " + g.getName()) + "</p>");
        htmlBuilder.append("<p>" + g.getDescription() + "</p>");

        htmlBuilder.append("<form method='GET' action='group/asXML'>");
        htmlBuilder.append("<input type='submit' value='view this Member'/>");
        htmlBuilder.append("</form>");

        htmlBuilder.append("<form method='DELETE' action='group'>");
        htmlBuilder.append("<input type='submit' value='delete this member'/>");
        htmlBuilder.append("</form>");

        htmlBuilder.append("<form method='UPDATE' action='group'>");
        htmlBuilder.append("<input type='submit' value='delete this member'/>");
        htmlBuilder.append("</form>");
    }


            /*htmlBuilder.append("<p>Following: groups</p> <br>");
            for(Group g: groups){
                htmlBuilder.append("<p>" + (g.getID() + " | " + g.getName()) + "</p>");
            }*/

    htmlBuilder.append("</form>");
    htmlBuilder.append("</body>"); 

    return htmlBuilder.toString();

}

}
```

When calling http://localhost:8080/myapp/myresource I get a (non-xml) overwiev of the groups I've created and with a button for each group underneath.
Now I want to look at a group:

I click on the form-button `htmlBuilder.append("<form method='GET' action='myresource/" + g.getID() +"'>");`

and I get exactly what I want: The GET method of group is called
`@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String listGroups(){...}` and I get an overwiev of each member in that group (the group class has an arraylist of members, which is displayed)

The only problem is, that I somehow am still on the myresource URL

when I take a look into my browser's address bar, this is shown:

http://localhost:8080/myapp/myresource/3 (if we clicked on the group with an id==3)
and I want it to be something like http://localhost:8080/myapp/group/3

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `MyResource#getGroupByID` is actually a Subresource Locator.

A Subresource Locator is a method in Resource class annotated with `@Path` without resource method designators such as `@GET` or `@POST`. If a path of the request URL is in a pattern of "`myresource/{groupid}`", the root resource and Subresource locator will be matched and invoked, and return an instance of `GroupResource` that will handle the HTTP request. That's why you get a HTML response from `GroupResource#listGroups` when you send a request with a URL of `/myresource/3`. Note that `GroupResource` as a Subresource class do not need to annotate with `@Path`. See [Subresources and Runtime Resource Resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced003.htm) for more details.

If you want `/group/3` to return the HTML response, you do not need a Subresource Locator. Instead, you need a Root resource of `GroupResource` annotated with `@Path("group")` and a subresource method with `@Path("/{groupid}")` inside. You can try something like below:

1.
Move all your logic from `MyResource#getGroupByID` to the `GroupResource#listGroups` and update `listGroups` as follows:

```
@GET
@Path("/{groupid}") 
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String listGroups(@PathParam("groupid") long groupid) {
    // logic from MyResource#getGroupByID

    StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    htmlBuilder.append("<html>");

    ...
}
```

2.
Update `MyResource#start` to provide HTML with form action of `group` instead of `myresource`:

```
htmlBuilder.append("<form method='GET' action='group/" + g.getID() +"'>");
```

This will result a HTTP request of `GET /group/{groupid}` dispatch to the `GroupResource#listGroups` method.